# Getting Error in Updating Chart Object from Access 2007 to Access 2013 or later

Tags: sql, ms-access, charts

I have an Access 2010 application in which I am using Chart object as:

[image: Chart 2010]

The code I am using to populate this Graph is as:

```
'getRunningAppObject Function
Dim appObj As String
Dim excelObj As Object
appObj = "Excel.Application"
On Error Resume Next
Set excelObj = GetObject(, appObj)
If Not excelObj Is Nothing Then
    Set getRunningAppObject = excelObj
Else
    Set getRunningAppObject = New Excel.Application
End If
'-------


Set shpGraph = GraphUtil.Object
Set odataSheet = shpGraph.Application.DataSheet
odataSheet.Cells.Clear

Set objxl = getRunningAppObject
Set objWKB = objxl.Workbooks.Add
objWKB.Worksheets().Add.Name = "temp"
Set objsheet = objWKB.Worksheets("temp")

objsheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Week"
objsheet.Cells(2, 1) = "Used"
objsheet.Cells(3, 1) = "Not Used"
objsheet.Cells(4, 1) = "Shortage"

While Not rs.EOF
    objsheet.Cells(1, i) = CStr(rs.Fields!week)
    objsheet.Cells(2, i) = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields("used").value), 0, rs.Fields("used").value)
    objsheet.Cells(3, i) = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields("not used").value), 0, rs.Fields("not used").value)
    objsheet.Cells(4, i) = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields("shortage").value), 0, rs.Fields("shortage").value)
    i = i + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

objsheet.Cells.Select
objsheet.Cells.Copy
odataSheet.Cells(1, 1).Paste
objWKB.Application.CutCopyMode = False
objWKB.Close False
```

I am trying to update this Graph Object in newer version, so in Access 2013 or 2019, when I tried to Insert Chart from Design Menu, it added the Chart like this:

[image: Chart 2019]

But when I try to populate this graph with the same code, I get error :
**Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method** on line 
**Set shpGraph = GraphUtil.Object**

What am I doing wrong?
How can I populate Chart object with a Recordset?

Comment: You are trying to convert Excel graph to Access? Data is in Excel? Don't see code that sets recordset. AFAIK, Access graph must reference table or query in RowSource property.

Comment: @June7 No this is a Access VBA Code only, recordset is set from other irrelevant VBA code only. Just wanted to know, like pasting the data in Unbound Object Frame, can we do the same thing in Chart as well?

Comment: This code worked in earlier versions? This is Access VBA manipulating Excel graph? I've never done that. Also never used Unbound Object Frame. I am using Office/Access 2010 so not familiar with the graphing in later versions, if it's changed. Why does the image look like Access?

Comment: Because this is Access only, not Excel. This is Access VBA filling an Unbound Object Frame by opening a temp Excel file, filling data in it from recordset, then copying that range and then pasting that range in the Graph back.

Comment: So Excel is involved. Access is manipulating Excel to configure data then you want to copy/paste worksheet range into an Access graph table? You said you want to 'update newer version' - this code worked with Access 2010? I will have to try it. But unfortunately cannot advise on 2013/2019 issues.